# Cumulative sum group by 15 min interval - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, cumulative-sum

I would like to get the cumulative sum group by 15 min interval.
eg:

table name: `myTable`

```
   id    name        start_time        faults
    ============================================
    1     a        06/07/19 23:30        1
    2     b        06/07/19 23:35        1
    3     c        06/07/19 23:36        1
    4     d        06/07/19 23:50        1
    5     e        06/07/19 23:54        1 
    6     f        07/07/19 00:05        1
    7     g        07/07/19 00:20        1
    8     h        07/07/19 00:25        1
```

Result:

```
         start_Time         faults
  ============================================
        06/07/19 23:15        0  
        06/07/19 23:30        3
        06/07/19 23:45        5
        06/07/19 00:00        6
        07/07/19 00:15        8
        07/07/19 00:30        8 
        08/07/19 00:45        8
        08/07/19 01:00        8
```

thanks

Comment: Your data spreads from 23:30 to 00:25 but your results spreads from 23:15 to 01:00. How do you define the range of the resultset?

Comment: paolo ricardos, any change you can post example data with matching source and expected results?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select trunc(start_time, 'hh') + (floor(extract(minute from start_time) / 15) * 15) * interval '1' minute as dte,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(start_time))
from t
group by trunc(start_time, 'hh') + (floor(extract(minute from start_time) / 15) * 15) * interval '1' minute
order by dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=05f83237a6e743d9c0c3c1f31fef2b89) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Shouldn't be ` * interval '1' minute ` in both places? Now minutes are moved to seconds. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives cumulative sums for existing quarters:

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ce3dbf179f3cfe8e2d51b0989149bd4)</sup>**

```
select date '1900-01-01' + tm / 24 / 4 tm, sum(sum(faults)) over (order by tm) faults
  from (select floor((start_time - date '1900-01-01') * 24 * 4) tm, faults from mytable)
  group by tm
```

If you want wider date range then generate it using `connect by` query and join with above using `lag()` with `ignore nulls`, like here:

```
with 
  flts as (
    select date '1900-01-01' + tm / 24 / 4 tm, sum(sum(faults)) over (order by tm) faults
      from (select floor((start_time - date '1900-01-01') * 24 * 4) tm, faults from mytable)
      group by tm),
  quarters as (
    select to_date('2019-07-06 23:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') + level * interval '15' minute tm 
      from dual connect by level <= 10 )
select to_char(tm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') tm, 
       nvl(faults, lag(faults, 1, 0) ignore nulls over (order by tm))
  from quarters left join flts using (tm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `group by` with dates truncated to 15 mins and then using `analytical function` to calculate the cumulative sum as following:

```
Select 
    start_time 
    + 15/1440 
    - mod((start_time - trunc(start_time)) * 1440, 15)/1440,
    sum(count(1)) over (order by min(start_time))
from your_table
Group by start_time 
    + 15/1440 
    - mod((start_time - trunc(start_time)) * 1440, 15)/1440
```

It is same as gordon's answer but using arithmetics. :)

Cheers!!